# No url other than domain.com are working in my django project production mode,

Tags: python, django, linux, server, passenger

whole django project works fine on localhost.  but when i uploaded it to linux shared server and deployed the project only domain.com works . other links like domain.com/admin or domain.com/xyz are redirecting to 500 Internal Server Error. most of the answers are linked to passenger server problem in passenger_wsgi.py but i can not find any error or problem in it

passenger_wsgi.py

```
import myapp.wsgi
SCRIPT_NAME = '/home/username/myapp'

class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME

        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

application = myapp.wsgi.application
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

Comment: That's too little info to help. That could be a relative_path issue while on the server.

Comment: Pretty sure you shouldn't be overriding SCRIPT_NAME like that. Where did you get the idea to do that?

Comment: @KostasCharitidis sorry i am new to django.it would be helpful if u tell me what more info should i provide.. thank you

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is given in a2hosting.in website's how to install and configure django on shared server section . link as follows .. https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-on-linux-shared-hosting